# How do I peroform django Model Validation to Exclude

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models

In the 1.6 django tutorial, after speaking about testing, it illustrates a `Poll` should not be viewed with the `index.html` view when it has no `Choice` (a foreign key in this model).  I've updated the model to make it simple to check this (in hoping that this would help...) in the `polls/model.py`

```
def has_choices(self):
    if self.choice_set.count() == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This turned out not to help since a filter can only be applied to whats stored in the database, which a function is **not**.  So then I was looking at potentially making a validation rule so anytime a Poll object was saved, it would update a new boolean object (`model.BooleanField`) so I had a data column to work with for this query.  However, it then occurred to me, that `Choice` objects would be saved, not `Poll` objects when I was actually adding a choice.

This all said, I can't think of how to add a filter to my `poll/view.py` to EXCLUDE showing polls who do NOT have any choices mapped to them.  I was thinking an `Poll.objects.exclude(....` would work, but then it gets complicated with joining a query against the Choices who do not have any foreign key's mapped to those results.

Am I over *complicating* this or is there an elegant solution to this?  The tutorial made it seem very easy but I'm finding myself going down an exercise far more complicated than the tutorial for 1.6.

Any answer works, but an elegant one always wins out of course!  I'm a fan of updating a model and reusing that for the objects.. but again if I need to have the model also update the database (not just a function), then I can do that too of course as long as the new column will have validation upon every `save()` event (and again, would that be for the `Poll` or `Choice` object!?).

The link is specifically https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial05/ under 'Ideas for more tests'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be overkill, but one fairly nice option would be to use aggregation to annotate the number of choices, and make that available on a custom Manager model which does the filtering. Something like:

```
from django.db.models import Count
class PollManager(models.Manager):
    def with_counts(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(choice_count=Count('choice')

    def choices_only(self):
        return self.with_counts().exclude(choice_count=0)


class Poll(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PollManager()
```

Now you can just use `Poll.objects.choices_only()` to return only the polls that have choices.

Comment: I believe a better name would be `has_choices`

Answer (score 1):

> This all said, I can't think of how to add a filter to my poll/view.py
>   to EXCLUDE showing polls who do NOT have any choices mapped to them. I
>   was thinking an Poll.objects.exclude(.... would work, but then it gets
>   complicated with joining a query against the Choices who do not have
>   any foreign key's mapped to those results.

Daniel's answer is great, and you can use it directly in your view (without modifying your models):

```
have_choices = Poll.objects.annotate(choice_count=Count('choice')) \
                           .filter(choice_count__gt=0)
```

Here the filter is a bit more explicit, you are stating that only show me those polls that have at least one choice.